# Load tinyMCE / wp_editor() via AJAX

Tags: ajax, tinymce, wp-editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to load wp_editor() through AJAX/jQuery](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51776/how-to-load-wp-editor-through-ajax-jquery)

There are several questions about this ([like this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51776/how-to-load-wp-editor-through-ajax-jquery), [or that](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65446/load-wp-editor-via-ajax)), but none of them provides a solution to me.

The situation:
I have a metabox. Inside this metabox I want to dynamically add tinyMCE editors.

The code:

PHP:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_insert_tinymce', 'insert_tinymce');
function insert_tinymce(){
    wp_editor('','editor-id');
    exit;
}
```

JS:

```
$.post(
    global.ajaxurl,
    {
        action : 'insert_tinymce'
    },
    function(response) {

        $(response).appendTo('#target-div');

        console.log(tinyMCE); // no instance of 'editor-id'
        console.log(tinyMCEPreInit.mceInit); // 'editor-id' not listed
        console.log(tinyMCE.activeEditor); // null
    }
);
```

The result is a editor window (with html and visual tabs), a upload button and a textarea but completly without buttons.

What I tried (as suggested in the other questions):

```
// In the response function
tinyMCE.init({
    skin : "wp_theme",
    mode : "exact",
    elements : "editor-id",
    theme: "advanced"
});


// In the response function
tinyMCE.init(tinyMCEPreInit.mceInit['editor-id']);


// in the PHP
ob_start();
wp_editor( '', 'editor-id' );
echo ob_get_clean();
```

This first one works, but I would have to set many settings manually, plus my custom buttons don't show up.

The second one obviously doesn't work, because there is no `editor-id` listed in `tinyMCEPreInit.mceInit`

The third one (output buffering) makes no difference.

---

I have noticed that `wp_editor()` adds the tinyMCE instances to `tinyMCEPreInit` and adds it via `admin_print_footer_scripts` hook. So I would have to dynamically update `tinyMCEPreInit` (without losing the instance of the main editor) and then fire `tinyMCE.init(tinyMCEPreInit.mceInit['editor-id'])` - **MAYBE**

Any help highly appreciated ;-)

Thanks!

Comment: Here: **http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/192132/33667**

Answer (score 3):

your post here helped me figure a solution.  Along with the mceInit property, I also had to retrieve the qtInit that wp_editor generates as well.

The following is the relevant code within my class.  Basically I have wp_editor run so that the javascript is generated.  I use hooks to retrieve the javascript, so that I can echo it out in the ajax response.

```
// ajax call to get wp_editor
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wp_editor_box_editor_html', 'wp_editor_box::editor_html' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wp_editor_box_editor_html', 'wp_editor_box::editor_html' );

// used to capture javascript settings generated by the editor
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'wp_editor_box::tiny_mce_before_init', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'quicktags_settings', 'wp_editor_box::quicktags_settings', 10, 2 );

class wp_editor_box {

    /*
    * AJAX Call Used to Generate the WP Editor
    */

    public static function editor_html() {
        $content = stripslashes( $_POST['content'] );
        wp_editor($content, $_POST['id'], array(
            'textarea_name' => $_POST['textarea_name']
        ) );
        $mce_init = self::get_mce_init($_POST['id']);
        $qt_init = self::get_qt_init($_POST['id']); ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            tinyMCEPreInit.mceInit = jQuery.extend( tinyMCEPreInit.mceInit, <?php echo $mce_init ?>);
            tinyMCEPreInit.qtInit = jQuery.extend( tinyMCEPreInit.qtInit, <?php echo $qt_init ?>);
        </script>
        <?php
        die();
    }

    /*
    * Used to retrieve the javascript settings that the editor generates
    */

    private static $mce_settings = null;
    private static $qt_settings = null;

    public static function quicktags_settings( $qtInit, $editor_id ) {
        self::$qt_settings = $qtInit;
                    return $qtInit;
    }

    public static function tiny_mce_before_init( $mceInit, $editor_id ) {
        self::$mce_settings = $mceInit;
                    return $mceInit;
    }

    /*
    * Code coppied from _WP_Editors class (modified a little)
    */
    private function get_qt_init($editor_id) {
        if ( !empty(self::$qt_settings) ) {
            $options = self::_parse_init( self::$qt_settings );
            $qtInit .= "'$editor_id':{$options},";
            $qtInit = '{' . trim($qtInit, ',') . '}';
        } else {
            $qtInit = '{}';
        }
        return $qtInit;
    }

    private function get_mce_init($editor_id) {
        if ( !empty(self::$mce_settings) ) {
            $options = self::_parse_init( self::$mce_settings );
            $mceInit .= "'$editor_id':{$options},";
            $mceInit = '{' . trim($mceInit, ',') . '}';
        } else {
            $mceInit = '{}';
        }
        return $mceInit;
    }

    private static function _parse_init($init) {
        $options = '';

        foreach ( $init as $k => $v ) {
            if ( is_bool($v) ) {
                $val = $v ? 'true' : 'false';
                $options .= $k . ':' . $val . ',';
                continue;
            } elseif ( !empty($v) && is_string($v) && ( ('{' == $v{0} && '}' == $v{strlen($v) - 1}) || ('[' == $v{0} && ']' == $v{strlen($v) - 1}) || preg_match('/^\(?function ?\(/', $v) ) ) {
                $options .= $k . ':' . $v . ',';
                continue;
            }
            $options .= $k . ':"' . $v . '",';
        }

        return '{' . trim( $options, ' ,' ) . '}';
    }

}


// the ajax respnose code
success : function(response){
    textarea.replaceWith(response);
    tinyMCE.init(tinyMCEPreInit.mceInit[data.id]);
    try { quicktags( tinyMCEPreInit.qtInit[data.id] ); } catch(e){}
}
```

Comment: After junrate switch wise tab not work and we can not write in text in it