# help on wp_editor via ajax load

Tags: ajax, tinymce, wp-editor

So I have been spending hours trying to figure out how to make the wp_editor() work on an ajax generated content. I bumped into this post: [Load tinyMCE / wp_editor() via AJAX](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70548/load-tinymce-wp-editor-via-ajax)  and tried the solution of [Mike Allen](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/23205/mike-allen). His solution almost solves my problem but then there is a problem with my Text tab, I don't see any button: **screencast.com/t/Emd2Da3UyThO**
My Visual tab on the other hand works fine: **screencast.com/t/JGWf4ivZfaGb**

Inspected my Text tab, I can see that quicktags aren't there: **screencast.com/t/qyvwWDnuEPnb**
But by checking on my window's QTags instances: **screencast.com/t/UAzIaZ7XOc5**
The description instance (which is not ajax generated content) has the **theButtons** attribute, while the tabdescription35 (ajax generated) doesn't have one.

Comment: you're talking about creating wp editor instances in markup that was returned via AJAX calls?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not good with English, but the answer is that the editor class calls the scripts needed in the admin footer (`wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php line 160`) :

```
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', array( __CLASS__, 'editor_js'), 50 );
add_action( 'admin_footer', array( __CLASS__, 'enqueue_scripts'), 1 );
```

So when you call the `wp_editor` function in your ajax, the scripts aren't printed with it, so you need to call them in your ajax with :

```
wp_editor('coool', 'editor_id');
do_action('admin_footer', '');
do_action('admin_print_footer_scripts');
```

This definitely works but it may not work as you want because you call all the wp admin footer so the perfect solution is to call only the scripts needed and this may take some time, I'll post the code as soon as possible, but try the code above I think it gives you an idea about what I talking about.