# wp_editor() in content that was loaded with ajax

Tags: ajax, tinymce, wp-editor

I try to use **wp_editor()** in content that was loaded with ajax, but none of the required files and some other configuration script not loaded :

The structure of ajax is something like this:

```
function get_test_page(){
   include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/page.php' );
   die( main() );
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_test_page', 'get_test_page' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_test_page', 'get_test_page' );
```

page.php :

```
function main(){
    wp_editor('','unique_id');
}
```

Editor is loaded but needed files is not loaded.

- `http://.../wp-includes/js/tinymce/wp-tinymce.php`
- `http://.../wp-includes/js/tinymce/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css`
- `http://.../wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&amp;load%5B%5D=...mce-view,imgareaselect,image-edit,word-count,editor,quicktags,wplink,thick...`
- `http://.../wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/{}.js`

Some related post but doesn't help me :

- [use wordpress wp_editor in dynamic/ajax html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519322/use-wordpress-wp-editor-in-dynamic-ajax-html/24324677#24324677)
- [How to load wp_editor() through AJAX/jQuery](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51776/how-to-load-wp-editor-through-ajax-jquery)
- [Load wp_editor via ajax](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65446/load-wp-editor-via-ajax)
- [help on wp_editor via ajax load](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106248/help-on-wp-editor-via-ajax-load)

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are doing. "loaded with ajax" is not much detail.

Comment: @Rarst I added more detail.

Comment: `get_page()` is a built-in WordPress function. You cannot redeclare a function. Fix this error, then try again.

Comment: @toscho this is an example, I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

Add `wp_editor()` in somewhere that works perfectly and hide it.

```
<div class="hidden-editor-container" style="display:none;">
    <?php wp_editor( '', 'editor' ); ?>
</div>
```

after that assign editor contents to the global JS variable.

```
EDITOR = $('.hidden-editor-container').contents();
```

Finally when the ajax page is loaded append editor contents

```
$('.editor').append( EDITOR );

tinymce.execCommand( 'mceRemoveEditor', false, 'editor' );
tinymce.execCommand( 'mceAddEditor', false, 'editor' );
```

Comment: I'd recommend against your solution. Aside from the missing `var` declaration, there are better solutions. Please see the answers in the "duplicate" linked question.

Answer (score -1):

Try add

```
do_action('admin_print_footer_scripts');
```

after

```
wp_editor('','unique_id');
```

Action 'admin_print_footer_scripts' load needed files for editor. In popup this action not work, because in admin panel is_admin() is false (see wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php function editor_settings). May be a bug.

Comment: Please explain _why_ this answer is helpful.

Comment: It helped me. I used thickbox to open the popup with editor.

Comment: Ok, it helped _you_. Now please explain **why** it helped.

Comment: Action 'admin_print_footer_scripts' load needed files for editor. In popup this action not work, because in admin panel  is_admin() is false (see wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php function editor_settings). May be a bug.

Comment: That's an explanation. Could you please add it as an [edit]? Then I can remove the downvote and not delete it. Thanks.