# How to reinit tinymce for wp_editor after ajax?

Tags: ajax, wp-editor

Basically if I call `wp_editor` via ajax it acts funny, I noticed it does not include 2 scripts it DOES include if i call it normally within a form (NOT thru ajax). I found some anwers like tinemce needs to be reinitialized and whatnot so that WP would call again the necessary scripts, but I can't figure it out.

My ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: vkrwps_admin.ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: 'EDIT_PROD',
                sv: sv,
                preload: vkrwps_admin.preloader
            },
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('div.mule').html(u);
            },
            success: function(response){
                var r = (new Date()).getTime();

                $('div.mule').html(response).find('img').prop('src', function(_, src) {
                     return src + '?v=' + r;
                });
                // call chosen on select
                $('select').chosen({
                    // placeholder_text: "Choose a product..."
                    'disable_search': true
                }); 

                // $('select.dropsearch').val(4).trigger('change');
            },
            complete: function() {
                // $('select.dropsearch').one().val(cf).trigger('change');
            }
        });
```

From what I found here: [How to load wp_editor() through AJAX/jQuery](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51776/how-to-load-wp-editor-through-ajax-jquery) I tried putting the following on top of my script that has the ajax call in it:

```
$.fn.tinymce_textareas = function(){
  tinyMCE.init({
    skin : "wp_theme"
    // other options here
  });
};
```

and then I changed my success to:

```
$('div.mule').html(response).tinymce_textareas();
```

But then I  get an error:

```
ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined
```

How do I make WP call the necessary scripts?

Comment: I think this is a tinyMCE issue you need to pass a selector parameter and therefore off-topic. However, I've been working on dynamic tinymce editors for the past 2 days (so I'm fairly certain you need to pass a `selector` parameter. My [WP Alchemy Grail](https://github.com/helgatheviking/WP-Alchemy-Holy-Grail-Theme) theme has dynamically (not ajax) added editors that might point you in the right direction. I have some WP3.9 code I'm going to push to a branch as soon as I can get my git client to cooperate.